# Correct terminology for "normalizing" data (making them add up to 1)

Tags: terminology, percentages

Let's say I have the data points 2, 2, 8, 10 (sum = 22) and convert them to:

```
2  -> 2/22  = 0.09
2  -> 2/22  = 0.09
8  -> 8/22  = 0.36
10 -> 10/22 = 0.45
```

What exactly did I do? Normalize them? Percentalize (sigh...) them? I'm pretty sure I didn't perform a 0-1 normalization (according to the formula found here e [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29)) since that does not necessarily mean they add up to 1.

What's the correct terminology to use when making a collection of numbers relative to the sum (add up to 1)?

Comment: Normalize is the standard term for a variety of such processes, including this one.

Comment: Note that the very first sentence of the linked Wiki entry says "normalization can have a range of meanings". What you're doing is  indeed normalizing, you're just normalizing your data relative to the _sum_.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain why I couldn't find any word for it. If you would want to be specific about this kind of normalization, say in a report or paper, what would be a formal way to phrase it? (Or would simply like you said, normalize relative to the sum do?)